# Función a usar para calcular una media de un único factor

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

De la siguiente tabla queremos calcular la media de las calorías de riesgo "moderado" de la columna riesgo. ¿Qué función tenemos que usar? Hemos usado varias y no lo conseguimos. La tabla es la siguiente:

[image: Tabla]

[Esta es nuestra hoja de cálculo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w0OXXpMKFaakWVTgOVxCfpePzRrB7EptTSj9w1HaFKM/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Mencionas haber usado funciones ¿Cuales habéis usado? ¿Cómo lo habéis hecho? Si añades un poco más de información de ese estilo es más fácil ayudarte :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías hacer uso de la función `AVERAGEIF` tal que así:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B3:B11;"moderado";C3:C11)
```

- El primer parámetro es el rango en el que buscar el dato
- El segundo qué buscar: "moderado"
- Y, el tercero, con qué rango de datos calcularlo

El resultado serían 896,6 calorías